# Field topicRepository in required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea

I was following [this javaBrains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdiYA.png) tutorial for spring boot

i've done everything correctly up to this point. But as soon as I made my TopicRepository interface and made one or two changes to my methods in TopicServices, suddenly this error popped up when running the app:

```
*************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field topicRepository in com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest.TopicService required a bean of type 'com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest.TopicRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest.TopicRepository' in your configuration.
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

SpringbootDbApplication:

```
package com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootDbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootDbApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

FunRestController:

```
package com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class FunRestController {

    @Autowired
    private TopicService topicService;

    @RequestMapping("/topics")
    public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){
        return topicService.getAllTopics();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
    public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String id){
        return topicService.getTopic(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/topics")
    public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic newTopic){
        topicService.addTopic(newTopic);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/topics/{id}")
    public void updateTopic(@RequestBody Topic newTopic, @PathVariable String id){
        topicService.updateTopic(newTopic, id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/topics/{id}")
    public void deleteTopic(@PathVariable String id){
        topicService.deleteTopic(id);
    }

    // expose '/' that returns "hello World"
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping("/workout")
    public String getDailyWorkout(){
        return "run";
    }

    // expose a new endpoint for frotune
    @GetMapping("/fortune")
    public String getDailyFortune(){
        return "lucky day";
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String get(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Topic class:

```
package com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Topic {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Topic() {
    }
    public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

TopicService:

```
package com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Service
//@Repository
public class TopicService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;

    private List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Topic("spring", "Spring Framework", "SF Description"),
            new Topic("java", "Core Java", "cj Description"),
            new Topic("javascript", "Java script", "js Description")
    ));

    public List<Topic> getAllTopics(){
        // for databse connection
        // connects to the db, runs a query to get all the topics, convert each row into Topic instances, and get it back as an iterable list
        List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
        topicRepository.findAll()
                .forEach(topics::add);
        return topics;

        // for harcoded list
        //return topics;
    }

    public Topic getTopic(String id){
        for(Topic x: topics){
            if(x.getId().equals(id)) return x;
        }
        return new Topic("hi", "hi", "hi");
    }


    public void addTopic(Topic newTopic) {

        topicRepository.save(newTopic);

        //topics.add(newTopic);
    }

    public void updateTopic(Topic newTopic, String id) {
        for(int i  =0; i<topics.size(); i++) {
            Topic currTopic = topics.get(i);
            if (currTopic.getId().equals(id)) {
                topics.set(i, newTopic);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteTopic(String id) {
        for(int i  =0; i<topics.size(); i++) {
            Topic currTopic = topics.get(i);
            if (currTopic.getId().equals(id)) {
                topics.remove(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TopicRepository:

```
package com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest;

import com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest.Topic;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

//@Repository
public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic, String> {


}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myName.springboot.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbootDb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springbootDb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties file:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

as you can see from the dependencies i am trying to use an Apache derby database in this case.

I've tried removing Autowired annotation from the repository instance in my service class... doesnt work...tells me that this.topicRepository is null.
I've tried add @service @repository in various ways to the service class and controller...doesnt work
Even my file structure seems okay to me

I think my main class is unable to locate the TopicRepository interface but how that is possible i dont know since everything else was working perfectly fine before this.

please help me out

Comment: `TopicRepository` is not a bean, hence the bean-container does not instantiate an instance of `TopicRepository`. Thus, the bean-container has no bean of type `TopicRepository` and throws the corresponding exception. Uncomment `@Repository` in interface `TopicRepository`.

Comment: @Turing85 did it, and still shows the same error

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I copied your code and created a maven project from it. The application stops with an error (`Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.`), which is expected since I did not configure any database. I configured an in-memory H2 database (see [this `baelding.com` article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database)), and the application started as expected. Please provide a [MRE], otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: @Turing85 yes I faced this issue as well. I added this : "spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration" to my application properties file to get over this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add @EnableJpaRepositories in SpringbootDbApplication main class
and uncomment @Repository in interface TopicRepository

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = 
{"com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootDbApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootDbApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this out and it gives me the following error:
Field topicRepository in com.myName.springboot.demo.springbootDb.rest.TopicService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to address this issue. The first approach is to use the `scanBasePackages` attribute in the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.example.something", 
"com.example.applicant" })
```

I have resolved the issue. By default, all packages under the `@SpringBootApplication` declaration are scanned. In this case, assuming the main class ExampleApplication with the `@SpringBootApplication` declaration is located inside the com.example.something package, all components under com.example.something will be scanned, while com.example.applicant will not be scanned.
his will ensure that all specified components are scanned. However, if the application's scale grows, this approach may become cumbersome.

The second approach, which I opted for, is to restructure the packages. I rearranged the packages as follows:

```
    src/
├── main/
│   └── java/
|       ├── com.example/
|       |   └── Application.java
|       ├── com.example.model/
|       |   └── User.java
|       ├── com.example.controller/
|       |   ├── IndexController.java
|       |   └── UsersController.java
|       └── com.example.service/
|           └── UserService.java
└── resources/
    └── application.properties
```

This new package structure allows for a more organized and scalable approach to package management. Now, the application will automatically scan the components within their respective packages, without the need for explicit configuration.

Hope it would help

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).